# c# UWP Camera preview

Tags: c#, camera, uwp

I created a camera capture with the code below:

```
CameraCaptureUI capture = new CameraCaptureUI();
capture.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
capture.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Windows.Foundation.Size(3, 5);
capture.PhotoSettings.MaxResolution = CameraCaptureUIMaxPhotoResolution.HighestAvailable;
storeFile = await capture.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
if (storeFile != null)
{
    BitmapImage bimage = new BitmapImage();
    stream = await storeFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    bimage.SetSource(stream);
    captureImage.Source = bimage;
}
```

But, it opens new window to capture Photo, and another window to crop it.

I want to access my camera directly and show it's preview in my xaml window.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi, do you use the "Windows Template Studio"? If so you can create a new app and select the CameraPage... there you have all the needed code... it's nice and easy

Answer (score 0):

> I want to access my camera directly and show it's preview in my xaml window. Any suggestion?

You could also make a camera capture with [`MediaCapture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) class, and it is used to capture audio, video, and images from a camera. For how-to guidance for displaying the camera preview. see [Display the camera preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/simple-camera-preview-access). To quickly get started capturing photos, audio, or video, see [Basic photo, video, and audio capture with MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture).

If you want to capture a photo to a file, you could use the following code to realize it.

```
var myPictures = await Windows.Storage.StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
StorageFile file = await myPictures.SaveFolder.CreateFileAsync("photo.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

using (var captureStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), captureStream);

    using (var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(captureStream);
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(fileStream, decoder);

        var properties = new BitmapPropertySet {
            { "System.Photo.Orientation", new BitmapTypedValue(PhotoOrientation.Normal, PropertyType.UInt16) }
        };
        await encoder.BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync(properties);

        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

And this is relative [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit).